# Cron not running

Tags: cron

how can I fix this one? Thanks in Advanced[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaQRE.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is something you have to set up on your server. It's worth having a look here

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/